# scroll bar selectable

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have a canvas with a scrollbar and I would like to disable the scrollbar in some way that keeps the thumb visible, but not selectable. I just want to let the user know that there is more information below, but I do not want to let him use the scroll to move down(this will be done with the movement of the arrows). I tried using the properties enabled but it does not work.

Any ideas???

Thanks.

Comment: Set thumbUp|Down|OverSkin styles to something with mouseEnabled=false?

Comment: Seems strange from a user experience perspective to display a scrollbar but not allow them to use it.  Why not let the user use the arrows OR the scrollbar?

Comment: @WadeMueller I know that it seems strange, but the user will be move with the hand mouse(like in adobe reader) but the scroll is only a visual element to know that there is more information above or below(also know a relative position inside the information in the canvas).

Comment: @alxx Sorry but I do not understand, you mean to set thumbUp skins or what? please could you explain me more briefly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canvas has `verticalScrollBarStyleName` used for scrollbar skinning. This is name of CSS style which will be assigned to vertical [Scrollbar](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/scrollClasses/ScrollBar.html), which in turn has following styles:
thumbUpSkin, thumbOverSkin, thumbDownSkin. You need some custom class for thumb with mouseEnabled=false. Set these styles to this thumb class name.